# Vb - Invoke Button using program

Tags: html, vb.net, web

I am using the below code to navigate to a url using vb.net

```
wb.Navigate("https://irctc.co.in", False)
While wb.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

Later I fill the username and password text boxes, within the form

```
If CType(elm, System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement).Name = "userName" Then 'Get User ID Element
    CType(elm, System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement).InnerText = "text"
ElseIf CType(elm, System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement).Name = "password" Then 'Get Password Element
    CType(elm, System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement).InnerText = "text"
End If
```

I use the below code to submit the button, after filling the form using the above lines

```
wb.Document.All("button").Focus()
wb.Document.All("button").InvokeMember("click")
```

the html section of the button

```
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button"  class="buttonSubmit" value="Login" onclick="return validate();" >   </td>
```

However it does not seem to invoke anything, tried assigning the result object of Invokemember method, came as "Nothing". It is not going to the document completed procedure. I have to fill the next form that comes after clicking the submit button. Also after the invokemember, how do i tell the program to wait till the next page loads? Once it loads, will the next form's html details gets updated in the webbrowser object wb? Or do I have to assign to a new object?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the use of `All` is the appropriate solution, mainly because it will always return a collection of elements, even if it only finds one.

Instead, try this:

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("button").InvokeMember("click")
```